# There has been an error processing your request in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento2

I installed some plugin after that will appear this error. how to fixed this error magento.

```
There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1558115809
```

Comment: check your logs for error and post it here as we don't know what is in your log record number 1558115809

Comment: This is that error log. `a:4:{i:0;s:63:"Mage registry key "_singleton/izberg/autoloader" already exists";i:1;s:2300:"#0 C:\wamp\www\magento1\app\Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 C:\wamp\www\magento1\app\Mage.php(477): Mage::register('_singleton/izbe...', false)
`

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59406/error-mage-registry-key-singleton-rkt-jscssforsb-observer-already-exists

Comment: I followed this bot not working properly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. you have to go `app\etc` and change the `local` file as `local.xml.sample`